# Schreibt man 230 VAC, 230 V AC oder 230 V-AC?

Tags: spelling

Ich habe schon die verschiedensten Schreibweisen gesehen im Bezug auf die Zusammensetzung  der Einheit Volt und der Abkürzung für die Spannungsart ([AC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current) bzw. [DC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_current)). Das Internet scheint sich  [nicht einig zu sein](http://ww3.cad.de/foren/ubb/Forum295/HTML/000474.shtml). Das kann ich nicht so richtig glauben und frage daher hier nach.

Ein Beispielsatz:

> Jeder Schrank erhält separat eine redundante 60V-DC-Einspeisung, sowie eine einfache 230V-AC-Einspeisung.

Ist eine der folgenden Varianten richtig? Wenn ja, welche.

- 230V-AC-Einspeisung
- 230 VAC Einspeisung
- 230 V AC Einspeisung
- 230 V-AC-Einspeisung

Comment: AC/DC sind englische Abkürzungen ohne gängiges deutsches Gegenstück und daher gibt es eine hässliche Sprachgrenze zu Einspeisung, weswegen ich auf eine symbolische Darstellung, wie *=*/*≈* ausweichen würde. Zudem besteht ohne Trennzeichen die Gefahr, nach dem V für Volt das A für Ampere zu interpretieren.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Erstmal ist 230-V-AC-Einspeisung ein zusammengesetztes Substantiv und solche werden im Deutschen »durchgekoppelt« und enthalten niemals Leerzeichen (siehe die diversen Beispiele zu § 44 der [Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf)) – auch wenn inbesondere die Werbebranche dies gerne falsch macht.

Obwohl es in einigen Kreisen nicht unüblich ist, würde ich *VAC* nicht zusammenschreiben, da es verwirrend ist und physikalisch unsinnig (mit Rechtschreibung hat dies jedoch nichts zu tun).

Bleibt die Schreibung der *230 V:* Stünde es alleine, wäre die gängige typografische Empfehlung, ein halbes Leerzeichen (U+202F) zu setzen, da ein ganzes Leerzeichen zu viel und gar keines zu wenig wäre. Bei einer Kopplung (also wie in Deinem Beispiel) stellt dies einen natürlich vor ein Problem, da kein halber Bindestrich existiert (und auch nicht schön aussähe und gut als solches zu erkennen wäre). Die [Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) geben zu § 44 unter anderem »2-kg-Büchse« als Beispiel an; die [SI-Regeln](http://www.ptb.de/cms/fileadmin/internet/publikationen/DasInternationaleEinheitensystem.pdf) sehen es genau umgekehrt und nennen explizit »10 kΩ-Widerstand« als Beispiel (die englische Ausgabe ist auch nicht anders).

Andererseits ist stark zu bezweifeln, dass sich die Autoren der SI-Regeln intensiv mit den Prinzipien der deutschen Rechtschreibung auseinandergesetzt haben, da sie im Anschluss zwar schreiben: »Wenn der Name der Einheit ausgeschrieben wird, gelten die üblichen Grammatikregeln [sic].«, aber als Beispiel hierfür »35 Millimeter-Film« angeben, obwohl dies gegen die Rechtschreibregeln verstößt.

Beide Regeln gehen übrigens nicht auf typographische Details wie halbe Leerzeichen ein. Eine allen Aspekten (Ästhetik, Rechtschreibregeln, SI-Regeln, Konsistenz) gerecht werdende Lösung gibt es also offensichtlich nicht.

Comment: [Schmales Leerzeichen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmales_Leerzeichen) » ALT+8201

Comment: Um »230 V AC« weniger holprig zu machen, gibt es natürlich noch die Möglichkeit auf »Wechselspannung« zurückzugreifen.

Comment: Die deutsche Rechtschreibung greift hier gar nicht. Die SI-Richtlinien geben ganz klar vor, dass Größenangaben wie `230 V` eine Entität sind und ohne irgend eine Form von Strich geschrieben werden. Die Regeln der deutschen Rechtschreibung „sehen“ also nur das Objekt `230 V`. Daran können sie nichts ändern, genauso wenig wie an einem Buchstaben. Das bedeutet, dass die Regeln da keinen Strich einbauen oder gar trennen können.

Comment: @Toscho: Ich habe den gegensätzlichen Standpunkt der SI-Regeln eingepflegt, aber sehe nicht, wieso ihnen Vorrang gegenüber den Rechtschreibregeln gegeben werden sollte.

Comment: Weil die SI-Regeln in diesem Fall spezifisch sind, die deutschen Rechtschreibregeln aber nur allgemein. Weil die SI-Regeln Standardard für ca. 7 000 000 000 Menschen sind, die deutschen Rechtschreibregeln aber nur für gute 100 000 000. Weil die SI-Schreibweise eindeutig ist, die Schreibweise der Rechtschreibregeln aber mehrdeutig. Weil die SI-Regeln konsistent sind, die deutschen Rechtschreibregeln aber nicht.

Comment: Weder PTB noch Rechtschreibrat kümmern sich um die Regualarien der jeweils anderen Institution.

Comment: @Toscho: Die Erschaffer der SI-Regeln hatten wohl kaum die Absicht, dass diese stumpf auf alle Sprachen und Schriftsysteme anwendbar sind, ohne dass es zu Problemen kommt. Angesichts der Fehler in der Übersetzung (s. o.) ist wohl kaum davon auszugehen, dass sie sich bewusst waren, dass ihre Regeln zumindest ein Grundparadigma der deutschen Orthografie (keine Leerzeichen innerhalb einer Zusammensetzung) verletzen. Ich sehe auch nicht, wo die Rechtschreibregeln diesbezüglich mehrdeutig oder inkonsistent wären.

Comment: Doch, genau diese Absicht hatten die Erschaffer der SI-Regeln. Und die Regeln verletzen auch kein Grundparadigma der deutschen Orthografie, denn die Orthografie weiß gar nicht, dass da zwischen `230` und `V` ein schmales, geschütztes Leerzeichen steht. Die Orthografie sieht nur den Block `230 V`, mit dem sie umzugehen hat. Die Mehrdeutigkeit ergibt sich dadurch, dass unklar ist, was das `V` in `230-V-AC-blablubb` bedeutet. Bezieht es sich vielleicht auf die `230` und bedeutet dann „Volt“? Oder bezieht es sich auf `AC` und bedeutet dann vielleicht „vertikal“?

Comment: @Toscho: Wenn die Erschaffer der SI-Regeln wirklich so dachten (hast Du einen Beleg hierfür?), waren sie ziemlich engstirnig, denn sie gehen z. B. nicht auf vertikale Schriftsysteme ein. Wieso sollte die Ortografie ausgerechnet hier nicht dafür interessieren, was innerhalb eines Blocks passiert? Selbst bei Eigennamen tut sie das. Und in Sachen Mehrdeutigkeit ist *230 V-AC-…* deutlich schlimmer als die ohnehin seltene Mehrfachkopplung, denn das kann auch als 230 mal V-AC-… (so wie *230 Autos*) lesen – ja muss man sogar, denn das Leerzeichen kennzeichnet im Deutschen nun mal Wortzwischenräume.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Nein, denn die `Einspeisung` ist singular. Würde sich das `230` als Zahl auf `V-AC-Einspeisung` beziehen, wäre das grammatikalisch falsch.

Comment: Und auch hier gilt wieder: Das Leerzeichen zwischen `230` und `V` gehört nicht zur deutschen Sprache, sondern zur Schreibung von Größenangaben.

Answer (score 2):

Die SI-Richtlinien geben ganz klar vor, dass eine Größenangabe wie `230 V` eine Entität ist und ohne Bindestriche geschrieben wird. Gemäß §40 [Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf), wird in der entstehenden Zusammensetzung das `230 V` durch einen Bindestrich mit den anderen Teilen verbunden:

> 230 V-AC-Einspeisung.

Man beachte, dass es sich bei dem Freiraum zwischen `230` und `V` um ein geschütztes, schmales Leerzeichen handelt. Die verschiedenen Textsatz- und -verarbeitungssysteme haben verschiedene Möglichkeiten zur Erzeugung eines solchen. Der Unicode gibt den Codepoint `u+202f` dafür vor, allerdings setzen das nicht alle Fonts und Systeme richtig um.

Alternativen wären:

> 230 V-Wechselspannungseinspeisung
>
> 230 V-Einspeisung (Wechselspannung)
>
> Einspeisung von 230 V Wechselspannung
>
> Einspeisung einer Wechselspannung von 230 V

(Nach Ideen von Wrzlprmft)

Answer (score 2):

As an electrical engineer who has occasionally had to decipher equipment manuals written in German, I think I would be horrified to see anything other than 230 VAC in any language. I'm just saying.

And although I don't read German with complete fluency, I think Toscho is saying something pretty similar in the comments field above, and with a little more logic behind his argument than I've managed to put.

Answer (score 1):

Ordered by google hits

- **230-VAC**
- **230 V-AC** and **230 V AC** (same number of hits..suspect)
- **230-V-AC**

I would separate **V-AC**, making it more readable. In any case, who needs to, will understand it.